# How to search a specific date from a given month and year in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been given a month like 1 for January and a year like 2020. Now I want to search for a date within January-2020. Suppose that day is 14/01/2020, so I'm trying the following code

```
select date 
from table X 
where date between to_date(1||'/'||month||'/'||year,'dd/mm/yyyy') 
               and to_date(31||'/'||month||'/'||year,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

but this range is for month January what if the month is February or April which have 30 days?
If this query is not suitable then how to achieve the perfect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the dates via `to_char` to extract the parts you want to compare.

```
select * 
from dates
where to_char(the_date, 'mm') = '01'
and to_char(the_date, 'yyyy') = '2020'
```

SQL-Fiddle for it is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/975cf/1)

Comment: It is upvoted only I cant see it marked as answered

Comment: It has been marked as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below,

To find first date and last date from a given date ,

```
select trunc(date'2020-02-14','MM') first_day,
       last_day(date'2020-02-14') last_day
  from dual;
```

**Edit :** after comments from other users
So the final query be like,

```
select date 
from table X 
where date between trunc(date'2020-02-14','MM') and last_day(date'2020-02-14');
```

Note: If you store date along with time you might like into the answer provided by @MT0

Comment: @Mahadi Hasan, not being critic to other answers , if you use like how you have constructed the query in your question you can leverage the Index on the date column if you have it whereas if you use any kind of function to convert to month and year you loose it and also you have to convert on both side to your input and the table column as well. At the end choice is yours always.

Comment: This would not find any values between `2020-02-29T00:00:01` and `2020-02-29T23:59:59`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It simply returns two dates rather than filtering a table.

Comment: @MT0, you went one step ahead. I mean you are right and I don't know how the dates are stored in OP's actual tables. If time matters then you are right it won't consider as you specified and should be done other ways as you did. Normally for first_day and last_day I follow this way. Thank you any way for bringing in this point.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff,  I am not validating data which I can't see and as I understood OP's question , it is all about finding first and last day from a given date and OP has his query already in place where he can accommodate bit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_DATE( your_year_value || '-' || you_month_value, 'YYYY-MM' )` to convert the year-month values to a date and then to get the upper bound you can use the `ADD_MONTHS` function to find the start of the next month:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_time >= TO_DATE( 2020 || '-' || 1, 'YYYY-MM' )
AND    date_time <  ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE( 2020 || '-' || 1, 'YYYY-MM' ), 1 )
```

*(Note: If you use `TRUNC` or `TO_CHAR` on your date column then Oracle will not use an index on that column; you would instead need a separate function-based index on the exact expression you used. Instead, by calculating the range on the year/month inputs rather than transforming the date column then Oracle will use indexes on the date column.)*

*(Note 2: You don't want to compare on the range `2020-01-01` to `2020-01-31` as this will ignore any values from `2020-01-31T00:00:01` to `2020-01-31T23:59:59`. Instead, you need to use the range from `2020-01-01` up until, but not including, `2020-02-01`.)*

So, for some test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( date_time DATE );

INSERT INTO table_name( date_time )
SELECT DATE '2020-01-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-31' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01' FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | DATE_TIME           |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-01-14T00:00:00 |
> | 2020-01-31T01:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=946986968dac32406d6e9fd6c740bef6)*

Answer (score 0):

You only want to check if month and year match so don't bother about dates. Instead of checking if a value is between 2 specific dates you could just check if the month and year match.

```
SELECT date
  FROM table
 WHERE TO_CHAR(date,'MM-YYYY') = '01-2020'
```